# Oracle, comparing issue

Tags: oracle, function, view, conditional-statements, procedure

Good day!
Folks, I have an issue when I want to compare multiple values. 
For example I have the Log Data for today, 23rd April. This is related to yesterday's job(22nd April) with specific name.

In my comparison, I should select all logs with their job dates with this specific name. I say that logs' dates must be bigger than our job with this specific name. There are other jobs earlier done with this specific name.
How can I choose only the last nearest one?

Please could you advise?
For example:

```
Table: Job
id
name
job start date
```

---

```
Table: Log
id
type
Log date
```

We have 3 different jobs with name "Coding"
and 3 different logs.

Jobs:

```
1, coding, 21-Apr-10  
2, coding, 21-Apr-14  
3, coding, 21-Apr-18
```

Logs:

```
 1. 1, error, 23-Apr-10 
 2. 2, error, 23-Apr-15  
 3. 3, error, 20-Apr-18  
 4. 4, error, 23-Apr-18
```

And there, when I want to execute logs and jobs, I must look to their dates. For example, error with id 1 is related to job with id 1, because log's date is bigger than job's date.

Or also, log with id 3 should be related to job with id 2.

Comment: log.date > job.date
AND I must select the maximum job.date which is less than this date data. How can I write this type of code in Oracle SELECT Query? Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Generally it is easier to for us to understand issues when the question includes some (simplified) table structures with sample data and the desired output derived from the sample. Also, you should **edit your question** to include additional information instead of writng a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, something like this might do the job:

```
select *
from some_table t
where t.date_column = (select max(t1.date_column)
                       from some_table t1
                       where t1.id = t.id
                      )
```

If it doesn't, please, provide test case (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data, which would be the *input*), and - based on that, tell us what you expect as the *output*.

**[EDIT]**

This is somewhat strange data model; jobs and logs aren't related by anything but dates ... anyway, here's code that returns what you described (at least, how I understood it).

```
SQL> with tjob (id, name, job_start) as
  2    (select 1, 'coding', to_date('21.04.2010', 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union
  3     select 2, 'coding', to_date('21.04.2014', 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union
  4     select 3, 'coding', to_date('21.04.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual
  5    ),
  6  logs (id, type, log_date) as
  7    (select 1, 'error', to_date('23.04.2010', 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union
  8     select 2, 'error', to_date('23.04.2015', 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union
  9     select 3, 'error', to_date('20.04.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual union
 10     select 4, 'error', to_date('23.04.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual
 11    )
 12  select j.id job_id
 13  from tjob j
 14  where j.job_start = (select max(j1.job_start)
 15                       from tjob j1
 16                       where j1.job_start < (select l.log_date
 17                                             from logs l
 18                                             where l.id = &log_id));
Enter value for log_id: 1

    JOB_ID
----------
         1

SQL> /
Enter value for log_id: 3

    JOB_ID
----------
         2

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But there, The maximum will not give me good result. Can you see my question again, because I have edited it.

Comment: It did not help me, may be there I should use some procedures? Do you have any advices regarding them? 
And, what is & before log_id in your code?

Comment: Why did it not help? It does what you said: for log ID = 1, it returns job ID = 1. For log ID = 3, it returns job ID = 2. `&log_id` is a substitution variable.